# How to Use IsLetter,IsDigit and IsChar From Android

Tags: android, char

The `Vb.net` Functions are

- IsDigit
- IsLetter
- IsChar

How to Use This Functions Android - Java

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Character.isDigit(char)` etc.

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Character.html